# Flutter: full clickable widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to make sure that there are several elements in one Card and they are pressed completely inside the Card as in the screenshot

[image]

I was able to do only as shown in the second screenshot, I will also attach the code as I try to solve this problem, thank you all for your help

[image]

```
          Container(
        alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
        height: 70,
        child: Card(
          color: Colors.white,
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                InkWell(
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text("123"),
                      Text("123"),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  height: 40,
                  child: VerticalDivider(
                    color: Colors.grey,
                    width: 15,
                  ),
                ),
                InkWell(
                  onTap: () {},
                  child: Container(
                    width: 300,
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text("123"),
                        Text("123"),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That happens because you have a `Padding` widget surrounding your `Row`. Move it down and wrap the inner `Column` individually with a `Padding` and you'll get the desired effect (if I got it right).

Comment: Everything worked, but now i can explain how to make widgets have an padding from the extreme walls

Comment: Now i need to write padding for each widget separately? which one is inside inkwell?

Comment: Yes, if you want padding to have the InkWell effect, you'll need to have it below your InkWell as well.

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is to make every single Text("123") widget to be clikable you can wrap each with a GestureDetector().

```
Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text("Stack Overflow InkWell"),
  ),
  body: Container(
    alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
    height: 70,
    child: Card(
      color: Colors.white,
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            InkWell(
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text("123"),
                  Text("123"),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              height: 40,
              child: VerticalDivider(
                color: Colors.grey,
                width: 15,
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              width: 300,
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        print('Top right text 123 tapped');
                      },
                      child: Text("123")),
                  GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        print('Bottom right text 123 tapped');
                      },
                      child: Text("123")),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

[!Console Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9qcPi.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9qcPi.png)